# Combine overlapping list ranges

Tags: python, list, dictionary, range

I have some data like:

```py
segments = {
    "seg1": [832, 1283],
    "seg2": [4219, 4670],
    "seg3": [759, 1210],
    "seg4": [3540, 4582],
    "seg5": [599, 1164],
    "seg6": [3843, 4582],
}
```

Each value represents the min and max values of a range. I want to merge key-value pairs in the dictionary so that overlapping ranges produce a single key-value pair, representing the total extent of those ranges.

So in this example, the `'seg1'`, `'seg3'`, and `'seg5'` keys should merge together, as should the `'seg2'`, `seg4'`, and `'seg6'` keys, producing a result like

```py
segments = {
    "seg1": [599, 1283], 
    "seg2": [3540, 4670]
}
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Does it matter what key name is used for the merged results, out of all the pairs that were merged? If it matters, what rule should be used to choose the key name? Should ranges be understood to be inclusive, or exclusive? That is: if the input is `{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}`, should those entries get merged?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the segments based on their start times.

Iterate through the sorted segments and merge overlapping segments.

Update the dictionary with the merged segments.

```
def merge_overlapping_segments(segments):
    # Sort segments based on their start times
    sorted_segments = sorted(segments.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])

    # Initialize variables to track the merged segments
    merged_segments = []
    current_segment = None

    # Iterate through the sorted segments and merge overlapping segments
    for seg_name, (start, end) in sorted_segments:
        if current_segment is None:
            current_segment = [seg_name, start, end]
        else:
            if start <= current_segment[2]:
                current_segment[2] = max(current_segment[2], end)
            else:
                merged_segments.append(current_segment)
                current_segment = [seg_name, start, end]

    # Add the last remaining segment to the merged segments
    if current_segment is not None:
        merged_segments.append(current_segment)

    # Create a new dictionary with the merged segments
    merged_dict = {seg[0]: [seg[1], seg[2]] for seg in merged_segments}

    return merged_dict

# Given segments dictionary
segments = {'seg1': [832, 1283], 'seg2': [4219, 4670], 'seg3': [759, 1210], 'seg4': [3540, 4582], 'seg5': [599, 1164], 'seg6': [3843, 4582]}

# Merge overlapping segments
result_segments = merge_overlapping_segments(segments)

print(result_segments)
```

output:

```
{'seg1': [599, 1283], 'seg2': [3540, 4670]}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo code

```py
segments = {
    'seg1':[832,1283], 'seg2':[4219,4670],
    'seg3':[759,1210], 'seg4':[3540,4582],
    'seg5':[599,1164], 'seg6':[3843,4582]
}
# Combined 
# segments = {
#     'seg1':[599,1283], 'seg2':[3540,4670]
# }

odd = []
even = []

for index, x in enumerate(segments):
  if (index % 2 == 0):
    odd = odd + segments[x]
  else:
    even = even + segments[x]

new_segments = {}
new_segments['seg1'] = [min(odd), max(odd)]
new_segments['seg2'] = [min(even), max(even)]

print(new_segments)
```

output

```
$python convert.py
{'seg1': [599, 1283], 'seg2': [3540, 4670]}
```

Comment: This answer just hard-codes which segments are merged instead of doing the asked-for merging of *whichever* segments happen to *overlap". (I personally am not downloading over that, just letting you know.)

Comment: OK, changed from `hard-code` to adding for loop.

Comment: That change still does nothing to check if the segments *overlap*. I think you're misunderstanding the question - you might be right, but I don't think asker intended the "shape" of their example to so narrowly scope their question. I would suppose there is no guarantee that all the even segments overlap, or that all the odd segments overlap. For example, if we swap the values of `seg3` and `seg4`, the merged segments should not change. For another example, if we change `seq5` to `[1, 2]`, the result should be three new segments: `[1, 2]`, `[759, 1283]`, and `[3540, 4670]`.

Comment: (I'm not even saying your answer is wrong necessarily. I suspect it's not what the asker wants, but the question is ambiguous/under-specified about this, and your answer could still be useful as-is.)

Comment: My understanding from questioner's result the `combine overlapping ranges` is find min and max  from odd and even item.

Comment: Right, "combine overlapping ranges" (and it just so happens that in the example they gave, there are two overlapping ranges, and their subranges are in the even and odd items). If the asker intended it to always be even and odd items, they wouldn't even need to mention overlapping, and they could just say "combine even and odd" directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def overlapp_segments( segments ):
    intervals = sorted( segments.values(), key=lambda i: i[0] )
    result = [intervals[0]] 
    for interval in intervals[1:]:
        if interval[0] <= result[-1][1]:
            result[-1][1] = max(result[-1][1], interval[1])
        else:
            result.append(interval)
    return result

    
segments  = {'seg1':[832,1283], 'seg2':[4219,4670], 'seg3':[759,1210], 'seg4':[3540,4582], 'seg5':[599,1164], 'seg6':[3843,4582]}
print( overlapp_segments( segments ) )
```

output:

```
[[599, 1283], [3540, 4670]]
```

Answer (score 0):

More compact variant:

```py
# Init.
result = {k[0]: k[1] for k in list(segments.items())[:2]}
rk0, rk1 = result.keys()

for x, y in zip(*[iter(segments.values())] * 2):
    result[rk0], result[rk1] = \
        [min(result[rk0][0], x[0]), max(result[rk0][1], x[1])], \
        [min(result[rk1][0], y[0]), max(result[rk1][1], y[1])]
```

Result:

```
>>> result
{'seg1': [599, 1283], 'seg2': [3540, 4670]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can progressively expand the range of segments, removing the merged ones as you go.  Start with a copy of the dictionary and update it based on intersections of ranges:

```
merged = segments.copy()
merged.update( merged.pop(m,1) and (min(m,seg),[min(s,start),max(e,end)])
               for seg,(start,end) in segments.items() if seg in merged
               for m in list(merged) for s,e in [merged[m]]
               if s<end and e>start)

print(merged)
{'seg1': [599, 1283], 'seg2': [3843, 4670]}
```

*I'm using `min(m,seg)` as the final segment identifier for the merged ranges.  This ensures that the smallest identifier is used which makes the identifier selection predictable and independent of range sequencing.  You may need to replace this with your own rule to pick an identifier.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using libraries, you could build a list of positions with associated segment id that combines the starts and ends of each range.  The starts of ranges add a layer level and their end subtract a layer level.  All consecutive positions with a layer level greater than zero form a new consolidated segment range.

itertools `accumulate` can be used to compute layer levels for each position and `groupby` can use them to from the ranges:

```
from itertools import accumulate,groupby

pos,seg,ops = zip(*sorted((p,s,o) for s,(p0,p1) in segments.items()
                                  for p,o in zip((p0,p1-1,p1),[1,0,-1])))
layer  = accumulate(ops)
merged = { min(g)[0]:[g[0][1],g[-1][1]+1] for i,(*g,)
           in groupby(zip(seg,pos),key=lambda _:next(layer)>0) if i }

print(merged)
{'seg1': [599, 1283], 'seg2': [3540, 4670]}
```

*On large data sets, this approach should perform faster than my dictionary update solution*